# How to show a message of error when call a method inside of code behind from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

I´m using blur event, so i check the length of the textbox when the length is more than 25, the idea is show a error message, but so far i cant show the message.

page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "SweetAlert", pMensaje, false)-> this is where i am supposed to show the message, right now i cant see anythig

```
<div class="grid3_1">
      <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Ubicación Exacta"></asp:Label>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtDireciónExacta" CssClass="item19" style="resize:none" Height="100%" runat="server" Rows="5" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:Label runat="server" Text="#Plano"></asp:Label>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumPlano"  CssClass="item21" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:Image runat="server" CssClass="item22"  ImageUrl="~/images/balloon_basic_blue.png" />
       <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="item23" Text="Folio Real"></asp:Label>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtFolioReal"  CssClass="item24" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="item25" Text="Area"></asp:Label>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtArea" CssClass="item26" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="item27" Text="Finca Madre"></asp:Label>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtFincaMadre" CssClass="item28" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="item29" Text="Tipo de Trámite"></asp:Label>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="droplistTipoTramite" CssClass="item30" runat="server" Height="30px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
       <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="item31" Text="Servidumbre"></asp:Label>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtServidumbre" CssClass="item32" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       </div>
```

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
 let txtnumplano = document.getElementById('<%=txtNumPlano.ClientID%>');
  
 if (txtnumplano) {
     txtnumplano.addEventListener('blur', () => {
      PageMethods.LongitudTxtNumPlano(txtnumplano.textLength);
            });
   }


}
</script>
```

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public static void LongitudTxtNumPlano (string caracteres){
 pMensaje = vMensajes.mostrarMensaje("No empty", "error", "Atención");
 int count=int.Parse(caracteres);
           
 if (count> 25)
    {
        Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "SweetAlert", pMensaje, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend doing the validation on the client side in the JavaScript. However, you will likely also want to validate on the server side upon save so that the validation can't be circumvented by disabling scripts.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use MaxLength="25" as part of the TextBox tag?